# Найти крайнюю точку объекта через bounds коллайдера этого объекта

Tags: c#, unity3d

подскажите пожалуйста. Хочу найти крайнюю точку объекта через bounds коллайдера этого объекта. Но эта точка находится не корректно. Как я понял проблема в разных расчетах координат(Мировые и локальные). Попробовал решить вопрос через TransfomPoint, но это не помогло.

```
    maxColPoint = new Vector3(col.bounds.center.x, col.bounds.max.y, col.bounds.center.z);
    viewGO.transform.position = transform.TransformPoint(maxColPoint);
```

Здесь я для наглядности пытаюсь присвоить искомые координаты(крайнюю точку объекта) другому объекту, чтобы было видно нашёл ли я нужную точку.

Comment: Для начала поделись с неспособными читать мысли на расстоянии, что за штуковину такую ты решил назать "*краяняя точка*". Ты походу не понимаешь что такое этот bounds, используя `Gizmos.DrawWireCube()` отрисуй его для начала и поверти объект, думаю это не то, что ты напредставлял.